# Grails 2.5.0 - reset database to use test data

Tags: database, rest, grails, grails-orm

I would like to use separate testing software to create at least a portion of the tests for REST APIs. The other software runs tests faster and is also more portable. In order to use the testing software, I need to reset the database to have certain test data. Is there an easy way to have a service that drops all domain objects and creates a new "bootstrap" of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to work with Grails environments. Simply define an environment `rest-api-test`. Within that environment you tell Hibernate to `create-drop` your database whenever Grails starts.

Then define your test data set in the `Bootstrap.groovy`

```
if (Environment.current.name == 'rest-api-test') {
   // insert your test data
}
```

Then simply use `grails run-app -Dgrails.env=rest-api-test` and wait unit Grails started your web application. Then start your external test tool.